# AsyncStorage mapping not working

Tags: react-native

I have code

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("Friends").then((value) => {
    this.setState({"Friends": value});
}).done();
```

I am trying to show in list using

```
render() {
    return ({
        this.state.Friends.map((o,i) => {
            <View key={i} style={styles.row}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.app_type_name}>{o.name}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        })
    })
 }
```

I am getting

> error evaluating object 'this.state.Friends'

Comment: Does `Friends` have an initial value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You render method should looks like :

```
render() {
    const {Friends} = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
         {
            Friends && Friends.map((o,i) =>
                <View key={i} style={styles.row}>
                    <View><Text style={styles.app_type_name}>{o.name}</Text></View>
                </View>
            )
         }
        </div>
    );
 }
```

Comment: Glad to help :)